# PostAdapter returning incorrect postids for posts

Tags: java, android, android-viewholder

Introduced some code that makes my `PostAdapter` return the wrong `postid` when I Log it, and the `post` isn't being liked... I am not sure how to fix it. App doesn't crash or anything, but I am unsure how to fix it.

Post has three `ImageViews`, and when they are clicked on they change color. That before was happening as it is supposed to, but now it isn't working... App doesn't crash, like I said, but when I Log it, I get back the wrong `postid`.

Likes aren't being saved to correct posts, and comments aren't being recorded.

Can anyone advise me on why this is happening?

**PostAdapter**

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public Context mContext;
    public List<Post> mPost;

    public Post post;

    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    public PostAdapter(Context mContext, List<Post> mPost) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mPost = mPost;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false);
        return new PostAdapter.ViewHolder(view);

    }

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        post = mPost.get(position);

        Glide.with(mContext).load(post.getPostimage())
                .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholderimg))
                .into(holder.post_image);

        if ("".equals(post.getDescription())) {
            holder.description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.description.setText(post.getDescription());
        }

        //Timestamp holder
        if ("".equals(post.getTimestamp())) {
            holder.timestamp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.timestamp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String timestampDifference = getTimeDate();
            if (!timestampDifference.equals("0")) {
                holder.timestamp.setText(timestampDifference + " days ago");
            } else {
                holder.timestamp.setText("Today");
            }
        }

        if ("".equals(post.getText_event())) {
            holder.text_event.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.text_event.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.text_event.setText(post.getText_event());
        }

        if ("".equals(post.getText_location())) {
            holder.text_location.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.text_location.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.text_location.setText(post.getText_location());
        }

        if ("".equals(post.getText_date_time())) {
            holder.text_date_time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.text_date_time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.text_date_time.setText(post.getText_date_time());
        }

        holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.like.getTag().equals("like")) {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid())
                            .child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                    addNotification(post.getPublisher(), post.getPostid());
                } else {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid())
                            .child(firebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
                }
            }
        });

        publisherInfo(holder.image_profile, holder.username, post.getPublisher());
        attending_event(post.getPostid(), holder.attend_event);
        number_of_people_attending_event(holder.number_of_people_attending_event, post.getPostid());
        getComments(post.getPostid(), holder.number_of_comments);
        getTimeDate();
        isSaved(post.getPostid(), holder.save_event);
        eventLiked(post.getPostid(), holder.like);
        number_of_likes(holder.number_of_likes, post.getPostid());

        holder.image_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("profileid", post.getPublisher());
                editor.apply();

                ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ProfileFragment()).commit();
            }
        });

        holder.username.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("profileid", post.getPublisher());
                editor.apply();

                ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ProfileFragment()).commit();
            }
        });

        holder.post_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("postid", post.getPostid());
                editor.apply();

                ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new PostDetailFragment()).commit();
            }
        });

        holder.save_event.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.save_event.getTag().equals("save")) {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Saves").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                            .child(post.getPostid()).setValue(true);
                } else {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Saves").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                            .child(post.getPostid()).removeValue();
                }
            }
        });

        //Setting ViewHolder for the attend_event icon (black)
        holder.attend_event.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("POSTID", post.getPostid());
                if (holder.attend_event.getTag().equals("attend event")) {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Attending Event").child(post.getPostid())
                            .child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                } else {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Attending Event").child(post.getPostid())
                            .child(firebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
                }
            }
        });

        holder.comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CommentsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("postid", post.getPostid());
                intent.putExtra("publisherid", post.getPublisher());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.number_of_comments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CommentsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("postid", post.getPostid());
                intent.putExtra("publisherid", post.getPublisher());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.number_of_likes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, FollowersActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", post.getPostid());
                intent.putExtra("title", "Likes");
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.more_options.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, v);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.edit_event:
                                editPost(post.getPostid());
                                return true;
                            case R.id.delete_event:
                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").child(post.getPostid()).removeValue()
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Event deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                return true;
                            case R.id.report_event:
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Event has been reported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return true;
                            default:
                                return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.event_menu);
                if (!post.getPublisher().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                    popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.edit_event).setVisible(false);
                    popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.delete_event).setVisible(false);
                }
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mPost != null) {
            return mPost.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView image_profile, post_image, like, comment, attend_event, save_event, more_options;
        public TextView username;
        public TextView number_of_likes;
        public TextView description;
        public TextView number_of_comments;
        public TextView text_event;
        public TextView text_location;
        public TextView text_date_time;
        public TextView timestamp;
        public TextView number_of_people_attending_event;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
            post_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            like = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
            comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            number_of_likes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number_of_likes);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            number_of_comments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number_of_comments);
            text_event = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_event);
            text_location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_location);
            text_date_time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_date_time);
            attend_event = itemView.findViewById(R.id.attend_event);
            number_of_people_attending_event = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number_of_people_attending_event);
            save_event = itemView.findViewById(R.id.save_event);
            more_options = itemView.findViewById(R.id.more_options);
            timestamp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);

            text_location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MapsActivityUser.class);
                    intent.putExtra("postid", mPost.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPostid());
                    intent.putExtra("text_event", mPost.get(getAdapterPosition()).getText_event());
                    intent.putExtra("text_location", mPost.get(getAdapterPosition()).getText_location());
                    intent.putExtra("text_date_time", mPost.get(getAdapterPosition()).getText_date_time());
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }

private void eventLiked(String postid, final ImageView imageView) {
        if (postid != null) {
            final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(postid);
            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).exists()) {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_event_liked_aqua_fill);
                        imageView.setTag("liked");
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_heart_hollow);
                        imageView.setTag("like");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

    }

private void isSaved(final String postid, final ImageView imageView) {
        if (firebaseUser.getUid() != null) {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Saves").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (postid != null) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(postid).exists()) {
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_darker_version);
                            imageView.setTag("saved");
                        } else {
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_save_hollow);
                            imageView.setTag("save");
                        }
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at

```
public Post post;
```

Whenever a row is rendered, its value is assigned to this one. When the user taps on another row, the adapter still uses this post to get the id.

Just simply get rid of the post and use position to access the item the user just tapped on.

Comment: So just delete the ```public Post post:```, and instead of it add...? Sorry I'm relatively new... I'm looking for what you mean by use position... You mean, for example, ```private void eventLiked(String postid, final ImageView imageView)``` here? Add ```int position```?

Comment: Try to remove public Post post. At top of your onBindViewHolder, use Post post = mPost.get(position);

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using setting a click listener in onbind which will overwrite the previous click listener so the post in that click listener will never be synced up correctly. You should move your click listeners to the viewholder instead. Or an easy fix is to use getItem(viewholder.adapterPosition) in the click listener

Comment: Where do I add the ```getItem(viewHolder.adapterPosition)```? In the ```onBindViewHolder```?

Comment: You would need to do that inside of the onclick listener, instead of saying Post post - getItem(position) at the top of onBindViewHolder. But overall you will fix a lot more future issues by moving the onclick to the view holder